# EditText does not lose focus after it gains it

Tags: android, android-edittext

At first my EditText had the focus as soon as the app loaded the screen and I disabled that with

```
android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

However, there is no way to lose focus after clicking the EditText. The focus is still there when I try to click outside of the text area. This also happens when I click on the EditText to change the value and press "Done" on the on screen keyboard. Does anyone know a way for me to accomplish this?

Comment: what do you want to accomplish by removing the focus from edittext field.

Comment: you are setting it to be be focused only when you are giving android:focusable="true" 
android:focusableInTouchMode="true". Otherwise set it as false and see.

Answer (score 3):

Focus only changes if you click on something else that can gain focus. Issue is: If you click on a button for instance you might not lose focus, unless you do what Mathew said. Problem with that is: A button whose focusableInTouchMode is set to "true", needs now to be clicked TWICE: Once for gaining focus and once for performing OnClick. A nagging issue, that was haunting me as well [right now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666380/android-evaluate-edittext-after-the-user-finishes-editing).