# Android: Evaluate EditText after the user finishes editing

Tags: android, button, android-edittext, textwatcher

**What I want**
I have an EditText, where the user can enter a value, such as 10.40. Once the user is done editing I am formatting his input to a currency, for instance the above mentioned value would get formatted to $10.40 (in the case of Locale.US). And I display that result in the same EditText that the user previously edited.

**Problem**
Because I am going to format (i.e. modify) his input, I need to know when he's done (so my formatting does not interfer with his ongoing input).

**What I tried**
TextWatcher is not an option, since it fires on every single edit, hence when the user enters one, zero, four, dot and zero (=10.40). I am currently using an OnFocusChangeListener which works as desired, BUT the problem is: I have buttons in my application and if the user clicks on a button after editing the EditText the EditText won't lose Focus, hence my formatting code never get's called ...

After this I tried messing around with the button's focus, setting it to FocusableInTouchMode - which results in the button having to be clicked twice in order to fire (which is a no go), since it gains focus the first time and get's activated the second time. After so much hacking around I was wondering if anyone got an idea as how to solve this dilemma.

**Some Code**

I add the following OnFocusChangeListener to my EditText whose function I described above. The EditText is encapsulated within a CurrencyTextbox (which is not really relevant):

```
@Override
protected OnFocusChangeListener getOnFocusChangeListener() {
    return new OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if (hasFocus) {
                //Member variable in the class which contains an EditText
                CurrencyTextbox.this.hadFocus = true;
            } else {
                // Thes EditText has lost focus
                Log.v(TAG, "Lost focus.");
                if (CurrencyTextbox.this.hadFocus) {
                    // We previously had focus, now we lost it, format the user input!
                    // Get current value of the Textbox
                    String value = CurrencyTextbox.this.textbox.getText().toString();
                    // Formatting the user input
                    value = String.format(//Doing some formatting);
                    // Reset the had focus
                    CurrencyTextbox.this.hadFocus = false;
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The problem however is, the above OnFocusChangelistener only get's called if my EditText loses focus, but it does NOT lose focus when I click on a button in my Activity, and as stated above, it is not feasible to set the Button's isFocusableInTouchMode to true, as it then needs to be clicked twice every time to fire.

Comment: Showing the relevant code always helps.

Comment: Not sure it would - the question really is very general, and I understand it's a general issue (and I am expecting a general answer/approach description, not a detailed code snippet). I can post some code but I am afraid it might not help much more to understand the described issue.

Comment: In addition: I don't have failing code, it's really not a code problem. It's just, that when on Android you click on a Button, that button does not gain focus (just the way it is), hence any other widget that previously had focus will not lose that focus (as the button does not gain focus).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I did some research and amongst other things I found [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=2705) thread. It elaborates upon a similar issue that you're having (of the button not gaining focus). Try the following: On your buttons, set setFocusable(true) (NOT setFocusableInTouchMode! As this spawns the annoying behaviour you stated in your OP), then  set the following OnClickListener on your Buttons:

```
    return new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO workaround because of android issue nr. 2705
            button.requestFocusFromTouch();
            // Do some stuff to handle OnClick
        }
    };
```

But they should probably just fix the focus stuff for buttons, the current behaviour really does cause some issues (like yours).

Comment: I gave it a try and it works :D ! THANK YOU, just what I was looking for!

Comment: An addition: It also works when not force-setting setFocusable(true) on the Button.

Comment: It worked for me also but I was wondering why the editText view is so complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Try using both `View.setFocusableInTouchMode()` and `View.requestFocus()`. You can use the `onKeyListener()` interface to detect user input and start a timer after each `onKey` Event to start your edit after reasonable delay.

Comment: I should use requestFocus on my EditText? thing is i have many widgets in my activity. The timer idea is inventive, but potentially erroneous ;). The user may enter the edittext and quickly proceed to the next activity, so if my timer is to slow it wont fire early enough and if my timer is too fast the problem explained in the question will remain.

Comment: You must requestFocus for the View you want to trigger onKey events (this may be the reason you need to click twice as you mentioned above). For the time, you do not need to stop the UI thread to run it. You can run the timer in a separate thread the will work in the backgroud while the user is typing in a new one (you have to take care of the garbage collector though and of creating alot of threads if the user is too quick)

Comment: I should add that it's a framework - hence what you suggest is not easily possible, as the Activites don't know their views - everything is highly generic, so I need to fix this issue in a more general way. And as for the timer: I wasn't worried about the UI thread, the thing is: Once the user quickly clicks a button to move to the next activity, we need to save all the field's data to the database, hence the complete dataset needs to be available on activity leave, trust me, the timer stuff wouldn work in this case, thank you though :)

Answer (score 0):

what is the problem ur getting? need to include `setOnFocusChangeListener` with ur `editfield`. just check it. and have to override the onFocusChange.

plz check for that...

here[enter link description here](http://www.anddev.org/hiding_keyboard_when_edittext_loses_focus-t12708.html)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I explained the problems of the suggested way of implementing in my question. I can't just override the Buttons onFocusCHange and provoke an button.performClick() because this will fire EVERY time the button has focus, which causes all sorts of issues - if this is what u were getting at. as for the EditText: I've already set an onFocusChangeListener. And no, you don't have to override onFocusChange - no need if there is a listener available for it, unless I am not getting ur idea.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is definitely an issue with edit text not losing the focus once it gains. After quite a bit of googling I found that its possible to achieve the desired result by only workaround. 
I had a similar requirement and I made a workaround to accomplish the above task and it works great for me. 
The workaround is as follows: 
Set the onClickListener for the editText and in the onClick event set a flag saying the editText was clicked. 
Set the onKeyListener for the editText and get the current value of the editText in the onKey event. 
Now, say you have clicked Done / Back Button in your activity/dialog. Here you can check the flags that got set when the editText was clicked. So if its true make any procedure calls you want.

```
EditText v = (EditText) layout.findViewById(R.id.framerate);
v.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.d(ExploreUIActivity.TAG, "Insided onClick");
        vClicked= true;
    }
});
v.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        Log.d(ExploreUIActivity.TAG, "Inside onKeyListener");
        value = ((EditText) v).getText().toString();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Now for the back/done button set the onClickListener and check whether the flag was set or not

```
back.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public onClick(View v) {
        //check the flag
        //if set do some stuff
    });
```