# UI with two EditTexts - When one loses focus, how can I capture any text that was changed?

Tags: android, android-edittext

My UI has two EditText fields. When a user selects one of these EditTexts, then enters in some data, then clicks on the second EditText, the information from the first EditText is lost and it reverts to what was originally in the field.

Example:

EditText 1 = "Hello"

EditText 2 = "World"

User taps on the first EditText, and changes the text to "Hello,", then presses enter: Normal behaviour. Text is saved.

User taps on the first EditText, changes the text to "Hello,", then taps on the second EditText: Wrong behaviour. EditText 1 reverts back to "Hello".

How can I fix this behaviour? Both EditTexts use the same `OnFocusChangeListener`.

```
 @Override
    public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
        String s = ((EditText) v).getText().toString().trim();
        s = s.replaceAll(",", ".");
        if (hasFocus) {
            System.out.println(s);
            //stuff
        } else {
            System.out.println(s);
            //other stuff
        }
```

I found that I can get the text that was lost in the `else` block. I can use this to set the text of the EditText. However, I've run into a new problem - If I add a radiobutton, I am not getting the lost text in that `else` block when the user goes from changing the EditText to clicking on the radiobutton. Instead, I am seeing the original text from this `else` block.

Comment: "so the onFocusChange method will only give me details on the currently selected edittext." This is incorrect. `onFocusChange()` will be called once for the focus leaving one TextView and again when entering the next TextView.

Comment: Please provide some code with how you are attempting to use `OnFocusChangeListener`.

Comment: "Both buttons use the same `OnFocusChangeListener`..." What buttons?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I will add code in a moment. You were correct - I was only doing processing on the editText that had focus. However the problem isn't exactly solved yet.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice and by Button, I meant EditText. Will quickly edit my mistake.

Comment: Alright, code added. I added that `else` statement for the edittext that lost focus. This will spit out the text that was not saved ("Hello," for example). I guess I just need to set the EditText's text here.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use two separate `OnFocusChangeListener` classes. This is a good situation to use anonymous inner classes.

Answer (score 0):

Performing action on when edittext lost focus solved my first problem.

[Android: Evaluate EditText after the user finishes editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8666380/android-evaluate-edittext-after-the-user-finishes-editing/8667724#8667724)

The answer from this question solved my second problem.